# How to find more than one matches on pattern using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find all matches of a pattern in a string and separate them, so that I can list them. Currently I can find the very first match, but want to find any other matches in the same string? 
I don't have much experience in c#, so any help will be great.

```
namespace StringSearch
{
class TestRegularExpressionValidation
{
static void Main()
{
    string[] numbers = 
{
    "123-555-0190", 
    "444-234-22450", 
    "690-555-0178", 
    "146-893-232",
    "146-555-0122",
    "4007-555-0111", 
    "407-55-0111",
    "a1b-Cd-EfgH",
    "a1b-Cd-Efgn",
    "UM2345678",
    "11/12/2013 4:10:06 PM              UM2345678                   UM2345678",
    "407-2-5555", 
};
    string sPattern = "[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}";


    foreach (string s in numbers)
    {
        System.Console.Write("{0,14}", s);
        Match m = Regex.Match(s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(" - valid");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(" - invalid");
        }


    }

    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Regex.Matches`

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Here's your code updated for multiple Matches.

```
namespace StringSearch
{
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    class TestRegularExpressionValidation
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] numbers = 
{
    "123-555-0190", 
    "444-234-22450", 
    "690-555-0178", 
    "146-893-232",
    "146-555-0122",
    "4007-555-0111", 
    "407-55-0111",
    "a1b-Cd-EfgH",
    "a1b-Cd-Efgn",
    "UM2345678",
    "11/12/2013 4:10:06 PM              UM2345678                   UM2345678",
    "407-2-5555", 
};
            string sPattern = "[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}";


            foreach (string s in numbers)
            {
                System.Console.Write("{0,14}", s);
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                foreach (var match in matches)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} - valid", match.ToString());
                }
            }

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the output is very messed up. I am trying to understand.

Comment: Put a break point at the foreach line and inspect the `matches` collection in the `quick watch window`. I tested this code before posting it to make sure it works. I got the 3 matches back.

Comment: Shiva, How can I get the starting position of each found string, so that I can extract them?

Comment: See the example on the `MatchCollection` documentation page on MSDN. There's an `Index` property that I think you can use. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer.. but...

You should wrap your "Press any key to exit" code in a conditional of some kind.

I prefer this method because it works no matter what debugger is attached (e.g. VS, WinDbg, etc), and no matter what build configuration is chosen, and *it turns itself off when not running under a debugger*.

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached()) {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Although this is workable as well,

```
#If DEBUG
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
#EndIf
```